# jquery mobile, php data attr not changing in php loop list

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

Hi I am using this code to pass a data-testid parameter

```
--- php loop here 
echo <<<_END
<pre>
<ul data-role="listview"> <li>
<a id="test" href="#test" data-rel="dialog" data-testid="$row[1]">$row[3] $row[1]</a>
</li> </ul>
</pre>
_END;
```

And I am using this to retrieve it on the links internal page #test:

```
 var b = $('a#test').data('testid');
    document.write(b);
```

The problem is that although >$row[3] $row[1]< loops correctly and changes the data-testid="$row[1]" stays the same when retrieved - even when the test number is not even in the database return anymore! It has stayed the same since the first one I called (which was the correct number). How do i get it to refresh?

I have tried no quotes and single quotes around $row[1] but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to include some more code, as in how do you populate the rows array and where do you call the jquery function.

I've just tested this code:

```
<?php

$rows = Array();

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        $rows[] = Array("row0," . $i, "row1," . $i, "row2," . $i, "row3," . $i);
}


foreach($rows as $row){
echo <<<_END
<pre>
<ul data-role="listview"> <li>
<a id="test" href="#test" data-rel="dialog" data-testid="$row[1]">$row[3] $row[1]</a>
</li> </ul>
</pre>
_END;

}

?>
```

And it works like it should, it returns this as output:

```
<pre>
<ul data-role="listview"> <li>
<a id="test" href="#test" data-rel="dialog" data-testid="row1,0">row3,0 row1,0</a>
</li> </ul>
</pre><pre>
<ul data-role="listview"> <li>
<a id="test" href="#test" data-rel="dialog" data-testid="row1,1">row3,1 row1,1</a>
</li> </ul>
</pre><pre>
<ul data-role="listview"> <li>
<a id="test" href="#test" data-rel="dialog" data-testid="row1,2">row3,2 row1,2</a>
</li> </ul>
</pre><pre>
<ul data-role="listview"> <li>
<a id="test" href="#test" data-rel="dialog" data-testid="row1,3">row3,3 row1,3</a>
</li> </ul>
</pre><pre>
<ul data-role="listview"> <li>
<a id="test" href="#test" data-rel="dialog" data-testid="row1,4">row3,4 row1,4</a>
</li> </ul>
```

So the problem is either in populating the array, or more likely in querying it in jquery. I  noticed that you're using the same id 'test' for the link, this is a bad practice. Change the link-id for each link and try again printing the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but im going to just do the whole thing in php - seems so much easier :)